# How to check if a URL is a valid RSS feed in scala

Tags: scala, rss

I have an input where users can add their URLs. Before adding them to my RSS feed list I should check if it is a valid RSS feed. Is there any way of doing this in scala?

Comment: Basically nothing, because I have no idea where to even start. I tried something by creating a new java URL object with the given url, but couldn't find any methods that could help me check its validity.

Comment: if it's not a trouble for you, I guess you can simply use some external site for checking validity, such as http://feedvalidator.org/

Comment: Do you want to know if the format is valid i.e., the URL is not malformed OR you want to know if the RSS feed actually exists ?